# Can the PIR sensor work without loop?

Tags: arduino

```cpp
void setManual(){
//do something like turn on and off the light
}
void setAuto(){
  for(;;){
     digitalRead(pirPin); //read data from PIR
     digitalWrite(ledPin, pirValue); // turn on and of the light follow the PIR's data
  }
}
```

My problem is when I call the `setAuto()`, then I cannot go to another method.
I have no idea about this. So, can the PIR sensor work without loop? Or how can I break this loop for go to another method?

Comment: Should you not get the *result* of the [`digitalRead`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalRead) function, to use it in the calls to `digitalWrite`?

Comment: Why don't you start with the adafruit example ?  https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/using-a-pir

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go into another method because

```
for(;;)
```

is an infinite loop.

You can read from a sensor using a timer, elapsed millis, in in the main `loop()` statement with perhaps a delay in between.  Lots of ways to do it.  But entering an infinite loop in a separate will probably not do what you want as your program matures to completion.  The main `loop()` in Arduino code is already an infinite loop and the one you should usually use.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an infinite loop using for(;;). You could try this instead:

```
void setManual(){
    //do something like turn on and off the light
    }
    void setAuto(){
      bool flag=true;
      int data;
      while flag {
         data = digitalRead(pirPin); //read data from PIR
         if(data == 0) { //Specify a condition that can if triggered would change your flag to false and exit the loop
           flag = false;
           //break;     //<-- You can also use this statement to break out of the loop.
         }
         digitalWrite(ledPin, pirValue); // turn on and of the light follow the PIR's data
      }
    }
```